# How should i remove header rule and instead display footer rule with page number centre align and project title left align

Tags: header-footer

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
%\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are asking for ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}   % remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.6pt} % set footer rule
\lfoot{Title goes here}
test
\end{document}
```